# WebDriver can't get dropdown menu element (Java)

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, junit4

I write a script on Java for Selenium WebDriver, and I have a problem with selected from dropdown menu.

Here's my locator:

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("FormElement_select_68_input_input"))).selectByVisibleText("Image");
```

Here's an error: http://prntscr.com/7jul03

Here's HTML code: http://prntscr.com/7jvou6
Need to select "Image" from this menu, but have an error.

Before I had the error like this, I can't upload file, it was because I need to switch to frame(0). 
But here I don't know why I can't select menu "Image" from DropBox.

Comment: Not every dropdown is a select element and so Select class cannot be used if the dropdown is implemented using the div and lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ID is dynamic, so you can't use it. Select will not work in your case, you just need to use two clicks

```
WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='select-pad-wrapper AttributePlugin']/input"));
dropdown.click();
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='select-pad-wrapper AttributePlugin']/div/ul/li[text()='Image']"));
element.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the element id you're looking for"FormElement_select_68_input_input" doesn't exist in your html, your code sample shows "FormElement_select_283_input_container" as the select box element. Try this:

```
Select droplist = new Select(driver.findElement(By.Id("FormElement_select_283_input_container")));   
droplist.selectByVisibleText("image");
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it is not Select tag.

Try with below logic

```
WebElement div = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[id*='FormElement_'] > div > div"));
div.click();
WebElement li = div.findElement(By.xpath(".//ul/li[text()='Image']"));
li.click();
```

Comment: Yes, you'r right, it's my mistake, it's not selector tag. But stil have an error: http://prntscr.com/7jwo9i

Comment: There was spelling mistake previously. I've updated my answer. (replaced id value as 'FormElement_select_683_input_input')

Comment: The same error. Unable to locate element: FormElement_select_283_input_input

Comment: check with latest modified answer. I'm just giving brief idea to solve your problem. don't try as it is.

Comment: So number in Id is dynamic. I've modified answer again .. check with that.

Comment: Again error: http://prntscr.com/7jxhbc
It's not dynamic, somebody make changes manually. May be I can't locate to this element because of this line: driver.switchTo().frame(0);

Here's code:
http://prntscr.com/7jxi9f

Comment: use driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); before doing above operation if it is not in iframe.

Comment: your code is not working, I try this one:http://prntscr.com/7jxo7r
and have this error: http://prntscr.com/7jxnid

Comment: Why are you using select tag again. It is not select tag.

Comment: ok, delete this line. But it's still not working with your variant

Answer (score 0):

As per HTML code screen, i am expecting Select class (selectByVisibleText etc) does not work. can you do one thing, try to click on required option directly. (may be click on "//div[@class='selectbox-wrapper']/ul/li[@class='selectbox_li'][contains(text(),'Image')]" , check one is it correct or not in firepath)

Let me know the result.. if it does not work, as said above you need to click on that input dropdown box and need to click on that Image.

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: thx, but Dmitry already proposed working solution, and I marked =)